# Reading a .dat File in C++ gives Symbols instead of Numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a .dat binary file in C++ as an exercise, however when I try to print out the contents of the file, I receive symbols instead of numbers.

Here is the code on how I read the .dat file:

```
int main() {
    errno_t status;
    std::FILE *input_file;

    status = fopen_s(&input_file, filename, "rb");
    
    if (status == 0) {
        std::string content;

        std::fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
        content.resize(std::ftell(input_file));
        std::rewind(input_file);
        std::fread(&content[0], 1, content.size(), input_file);
        std::fclose(input_file);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::cout << content[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried it using C++ `fstream`.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream input_file(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (input_file) {
        std::string content;

        input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        content.resize(input_file.tellg());
        input_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        input_file.read(&content[0], contents.size());
        input_file.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            std::cout << content[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to print the content of `content`, it returns `ⁿ\|Cⁿ\|Cⁿ\` (for the first 10 elements), which corresponds to the first 10 bytes of the file: `fc 5c 7c 43 fc 5c 7c 43 fc 5c` (according to a Hex Editor).

I could easily open the file in Python by using

```
data = numpy.fromfile(filename, "=f")
```

and returns the following (which I expect),

```
array([252.36322, 252.36322, 252.36322, ..., 239.38304, 239.38304,
       239.38304], dtype=float32)
```

I also looked into the number of bytes each element should have using Python, and it returned 4, which matches with the output of `std::ftell(input_file)` (the file should have 36 million points), but I tried changing `1` to `4` in the line `std::fread(&content[0], 1, content.size(), input_file);` and it returns an empty `content`. Also, as far as I know, the file doesn't contain any headers, so I think the data should begin at the very first bit.

So, how could I open and read the .dat file in C++ so that it returns the same value as Python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: although this technically is C++, you're using C library functions. Maybe look into C++'s own `<fstream>`

Comment: `.dat` is just an arbitrary extension. File extensions are just convention. What does make a difference is whether the file contains text or binary data. Please show the contents of the file. Your link is for a download. All necessary information should be in the question, it should not be necessary to dowload a file

Comment: I have added my attempt using `<fstream>`. Unfortunately, the output of the file is still a list of symbols.

Comment: Please explain to your nearest rubber duck the meaning of `"=f"` in the call to `fromFile`, and where exactly its counterpart can be found in your C++ code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I apologise for this, the file is in binary. I added the first ten bytes as seen in a Hex Editor.
@n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m: The `=f` flag is for reading the data as a float type. So, I guess my part of the question is how to implement this in the C++ code.
@Andreas Wenzel: I am printing the data using std::cout << content[0];

Comment: Yes, but I inserted the `std::cout << content` inside a loop. I apologise for the confusion, I added this loop into the scripts.

Comment: @magus_e: Yes, I noticed. That is why I have now deleted my comments (because they are no longer relevant, since you have fixed the question in that respect).

Comment: So if you're reading a numpy file you need to parse it according to the [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#:~:text=The%20.,machine%20with%20a%20different%20architecture.&text=npz%20file%20is%20a%20zip%20file%20containing%20multiple%20.) docs. Otherwise it won't make any sense.

Comment: @Mgetz: I am not reading a Numpy file. I have a binary .dat file from another source, and I can open it using Numpy. I am trying to open this file using C++ as an exercise.

Comment: @magus_e pardon my confusion but when you show yourself opening it with numpy that would indicate the format. Regardless parsing a binary file should be done according to the file spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cout << content[i];
}
```

is printing the data by interpreting the data as representing the [character codes](https://asciichart.com/) of invidual characters. However, this is not what the data represents. The data actually represents single-precision floating-point numbers. Therefore, you should interpret it as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    float f;
    std::memcpy( &f, content.data() + i * sizeof f, sizeof f );
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Note that you must `#include <cstring>` in order to use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

Comment: Thank you! The outputs now match with the Python.

Answer (score -1):

You should use C++'s fstream instead of C functions as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream in("batFile.bat");

    if (in) 
    {
        std::string content;

        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(in, line))
        {
            content += line + '\n';
        }
        std::cout << content;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### batFile.bat

```
12
12
13
13
```

### output

```
12
12
13
13
```

As you can see this code works perfectly fine, you may modify it as per your requirements :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried using this method, but unfortunately, the output remains the same.

Comment: Try replacing the contents of your file with the content shown in the answer. Tell me if it worked.

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, the problem is that the input data is binary, not text, and represents floating-point numbers.